# Windows 10 UAP - Compass.GetDefault() is sometimes null

Tags: win-universal-app, compass

Working on a windows 10 UAP and need Compass data. Has been working most the time, but every now and again Compass.GetDefault() returns null and it'll keeps doing it till I reset the device.

Thought it was my device at first, but it is randomly hitting the issue when submitting to the store and failing as a result.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: If this is a unavoidable device problem, can you catch that null reference exception and show a message to the user and tell user to reset the device?

Comment: Yer, that's where I was going, but not sure if the MS store tests will be too happy with that solution.

Might have to try have the code re-try a couple times and see if it's just delayed and not a permanent issue.